# Combine columns from three different tables into a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am new to SQL and I am not sure what to Google. I have three tables with different numbers of columns. I would like to combine these following three tables into a single column(no duplicates).

**Table1**

```
Col1          Col2            Col3
1              a               aa
2              b               ab
3              c               bb
```

**Table2**

```
Col1         Col2
123          Test
456          Test2
346          Test3
```

**Table3**

```
Col1         Col2        Col3       Col4
5695         93234       ABC        CDE
4534         92349       MSF        KSK
3244         12323       SLE        SNE
```

**Expected Output:**

```
FileOutput
1aaa
123Test
569593234ABCCDE
2bab
456Test2
453492349MSFKSK
...
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: so you want each table's columns concatenated into a single string, and then you want to combine all rows from all tables, alternating tables in each row? (And how do you expect anything to be sorted?)

Comment: Yes, I am not worried about the order. But, they should have all been combined into a single column output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you would want to Google would be: `UNION` and `CONCAT`.

> Note: CONCAT is not supported in prior versions to SQL Server 2012.

To get your expected output, I would do this:

```
select 
  concat(cast(col1 as varchar(10)),col2,col3) as FileOutput 
from table1
UNION
select 
  concat(cast(col1 as varchar(10)),col2) as FileOutput 
from table2
UNION
select 
  concat(cast(col1 as varchar(10)),cast(col2 as varchar(10)),col3,col4) as FileOutput 
from table3
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c209/3/0)

Comment: @TabAlleman . . . This answers the question and there is no need for the subqueries to return different numbers of columns.

Comment: comment deleted, forgot about the CONCAT

Comment: Oh, never use `union` for this type of query, unless you really want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.  That's why I liked the other answers better.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I forgot to mention that I want to remove any duplicate combined values. So, this is okay for me!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you would parse the data, but you could do this:

```
select convert(varchar(100), col1) + convert(varchar(100), col2) + convert(varchar(100), col3) as fileOutput
from table1
union all 
select convert(varchar(100), col1) + convert(varchar(100), col2) as fileOutput
from table2
union all 
select convert(varchar(100), col1) + convert(varchar(100), col2) + 
convert(varchar(100), col3) + convert(varchar(100), col4) as fileOutput
from table4
```

note not knowing your column data types, your varchar(100) may need to expand, or could potentially shrink depending on your data.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine them using `+` (may need to `cast` your `int`s as `varchar`s for this to work), then put them all in one table using `union all`.  Example:

```
Select cast(col1 as varchar(100)) + col2 + col3
from Table1
union all
select cast(col1 as varchar(100)) + col2
from Table2
```

etc.

Note: be sure to use `union all` rather than `union` if you want to keep any duplicates you may create.

Comment: This would be correct if you gave `varchar` a nice long length.  Never use `varchar()` in SQL Server without a length parameter.  The default length varies by context; it might not be big enough; and the resulting errors are hard to find.